# Is it possible to set up an ODBC connected Excel spreadsheet on SharePoint 2007 with a Standard license?

Tags: 2007, licensing, excel-services, excel

I know that many database connections are possible with the Enterprise version of SharePoint Server 2007.  Is it possible to make a custom solution to set up a connection?  If it depends on the type of connection, could I be given a place for guidance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to ODBC data sources, what the Enterprise License gives you in Excel Services is the ability to externalize your data connections so they may be reused across workbooks.  With the Standard License, you do not get Excel Calculation Services, so what you end up with essentially is Excel files stored in a document library.  To that end, you may do anything with ODBC data sources that you can do from your workstation, because you must open the Excel doc on your workstation to use it -- SharePoint is simply serving as a repository.